# Rsyslog cannot find kafka module

Tags: apache-kafka, rsyslog

I have rsyslogd  8.2001.0.de755a2f982d (aka 2020.01)

In a Ubuntu Server:

Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial

I have installed rsyslog-kafka package

```
server:/etc/rsyslog.d# apt-get install rsyslog-kafka
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
rsyslog-kafka is already the newest version (8.2001.0~20191115101825-0adiscon1xenial).
```

And I get the following error:

```
   rsyslogd: could not load module 'omkafka', errors: trying to load module /usr/lib/rsyslog/omkafka.so: 
   /usr/lib/rsyslog/omkafka.so: undefined symbol: sqrt [v8.2001.0.de755a2f982d try 
   https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2066 ]
rsyslogd: module name 'omkafka' is unknown [v8.2001.0.de755a2f982d try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2209 ]
```

Of course if you do "ls -la /usr/lib/rsyslog" the module is there...

```
server:/etc/rsyslog.d# ls -lah /usr/lib/rsyslog/
total 2.5M
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Nov 15 14:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 85 root root 4.0K Nov 15 10:57 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  53K Nov 15 10:31 imfile.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  29K Nov 15 10:31 imjournal.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 918K Nov 15 10:31 imkafka.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  20K Nov 15 10:31 imklog.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 934K Nov 15 10:31 omkafka.so
```

I uninstalled and installed again both packages (rsyslog and rsyslog-kafka) but no luck... I'm blocked

any help is wellcome

thank you very much in advance!

Comment: please try `apt-get update` && `apt-get install rsyslog`

Comment: Hi Avi, thank you, done It says I have already the newest version

Answer (score 2):

`rsyslog` supports Kafka, you should just install the `rsyslog-kafka` package, then write simple configuration in `/etc/rsyslog.conf` to stream logs in/to Kafka.